# Can't access Server 2008 Machines Resources (Printers, File Shares) or RDP

Tags: windows

I have been looking for something to point me in the right direction but have so far been unsuccessful.

We have an old 2008 Machine that I rebooted this morning and ever since I cannot access the files shares, or any printers I print to via the server and I can't access the server via Remote Desktop. We have some mapped drives to shared folders that no longer work on any clients. I can print to the printers from the server or directly from clients but if I try to print from a client via the server share of the printer it wont work for multiple printers. The remote desktop says it isn't available. I have checked all of the settings on the server and they all seem correct. I can see all the shared folders via the server itself but as soon as you click on the server in the network list on a client it says it cant access the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am really scratching my head.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Server has IP set through DHCP or? Maybe IP has changed. Is the local Firewall enabled?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. The IP is a static one set manually on the NIC. I have double checked it and the IP is correct and still the same. The Firewall is on, although oddly enough i am logged in as administrator and it says I cannot change the settings. Something to do with having to change the group policy? I have checked the firewall setting though and everything that should be allowed is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so have figured out what was causing a problem. Routing and Remote Access Service. I realised after a rebooted everything started working but then about 10 minutes after the server booted up everything stopped working again. Having looked down the service list I noticed some were delayed starts. I set the Routing and Remote Access service to manual and rebooted and turns out this resolved the problem. I don’t need the service on that server and my guess is it’s conflicting with the service on the other server.